# Is there a memory efficient way to transform html files using dbt python models and load the result into snowflake?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am trying to use dbt python models for a use case I have. In one table I have imported some html files. The structure looks like this:

| filename | html content | ingested_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a.html |  | <timestamp_a> |
| b.html |  | <timestamp_b> |

The html contains a few tables. Let's say I want to extract data from one html table that looks like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| a_content_1 | b_content_1 |
| a_content_2 | b_content_2 |

I want the Snowflake table to look like this

| filename | ingested_at | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_html | timestamp_a | a_content_1 | b_content_1 |
| a_html | timestamp_a | a_content_2 | b_content_2 |

etc.

I am currently on a step where I have the resulting dataframe in the format

```
[
(a_html, timestamp_a, a_content_1, b_content_1),
(a_html, timestamp_a, a_content_2, b_content_2),
...
]
```

At first I tried using pandas for this, but that failed immediately because of an out of memory exception.

The obvious solution is to instantiate a new Snowpark dataframe and pass in this huge array, but that would require me to keep the whole array in memory and then load it in a Snowpark dataframe which is all quite memory intensive.

Is there a memory efficient method to create a new Snowpark dataframe which would somehow lazily load this into the database?

Comment: First thing to check is the [Snowpark-optimized Warehouses](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-snowpark-optimized), second [Vectorized Python UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-batch)

Comment: I'd love to help - but first I need your help with clear steps for me to reproduce your current situation